# Angular2 Http get display wrong data in html

Tags: angular, firebase, rss, ionic2, http-get

does anyone know whether this is a bug or an issue with my codes?

Currently i am trying to use forEach with http get to retrieve the rss feed and it only display the data from one rss feed which should not be the case. However , in the console log it is emulating the right behaviour.

Please help , i been trying to solve for a few days.

**My Html code**

```
<div *ngFor="let category of favouritecategories | async"><h3 class="header" [id]="category.name">{{category.name}}</h3>

<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of xmlItemsApac; let i=index" #slidingItem>

  <ion-item *ngIf="i<articlecount" text-wrap>
    <div class (click)="openbrowser(item.link)"><h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    <p class="block-with-text"> {{item.description}}</p></div>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="right">
    <button ion-button color="custom" (click)="bookmark(item.title,item.description,item.link,slidingItem)"><ion-icon name="bookmark"></ion-icon>Bookmark</button>
  </ion-item-options>

  <ion-item *ngIf="i>articlecount" [hidden]="!showMoreAmericas" text-wrap>
    <div class (click)="openbrowser(item.link)"><h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    <p class="block-with-text"> {{item.description}}</p></div>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="right">
    <button ion-button color="custom" (click)="bookmark(item.title,item.description,item.link,slidingItem)"><ion-icon name="bookmark"></ion-icon>Bookmark</button>
  </ion-item-options>

</ion-item-sliding>

<button ion-item (click)="toggleMoreArticle()" text-center detail-none large>
  <h4 class="showMoreText"><ion-icon name="arrow-down" *ngIf="!arrows"></ion-icon>
  <ion-icon name="arrow-up" *ngIf="arrow"></ion-icon> {{buttonText}}</h4>
</button><br/>

</div>
```

**My Typescript**

```
this.af.database.list(`/users/${userid}/favourites`)
  .subscribe(snapshots => {
    snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
      this.Apac = this.http.get( snapshot.regions[0].rss)
        this.Apac.map(res => res.text())
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.parseXML(data)
              .then((data) => {
                this.xmlItemsApac = data;
                console.log(this.xmlItemsApac)
              });
          });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing your rss entry in `this.xmlItemsApac`.You need to initialize it to empty array.
`this.xmlItemsApac=[]`

and push the values

```
this.af.database.list(`/users/${userid}/favourites`)
  .subscribe(snapshots => {
    snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
      this.Apac = this.http.get( snapshot.regions[0].rss)
        this.Apac.map(res => res.text())
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.parseXML(data)
              .then((data) => {
                this.xmlItemsApac.push(data);
                console.log(this.xmlItemsApac)
              });
          });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hi @suraj , is there anything i need to do for my html as well but it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: the ion-item-sliding should be inside `ion-list`

Comment: yes it's inside ion-list already but it's not displaying anything on my view and in my console log it's rendering 3 array